# Find if incoming data exists in sql table

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a form where the user is supposed to input data (name, streetname, streetnumber) and then i want to check if that data exists in the table (name, streetname+streetnumber) so i can use that row instead of making a new one. 
Is there an easy way to do this or will i have to fetch the data into an array and search that somehow?

I have this code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 725G54_proj_address VALUES           (NULL,'$streetname','$streetnumber')";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$address=mysql_insert_id();
echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . $address;
echo "<br>";


$sql = "INSERT INTO 725G54_proj_contact VALUES ('Null','$name','$telephonenumber')";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$contact = mysql_insert_id();
echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . $contact;


$sql = "INSERT INTO 725G54_proj_LivesAt VALUES ('$contact','$address')";
$result3 = mysql_query($sql,$con);`enter code here`
```

What i would like to is is find out if example Mainstreet 31 allready exists in proj_address and if it does, use its autoincremented id for the insert into proj_Lives_at.

Edit:
I decided to go with sending queries to check if the data existed.
I load that into a variable and check if it is empty, but there is some problem so that "if(empty)" doesn't work as it should. the other way around ("if(!empty)") works however.

the query and loading look like this:

```
$sql2="SELECT 725G54_proj_address.Address_ID, GROUP_CONCAT( cast( concat( 725G54_proj_address.Street_Name, ' ', 725G54_proj_address.Street_Number ) AS char ) SEPARATOR ', ') AS addresses
    FROM 725G54_proj_address
    WHERE 725G54_proj_address.Street_Name = '$streetname' AND 725G54_proj_address.Street_Number= '$streetnumber'
    GROUP BY 725G54_proj_address.Address_ID
    ORDER BY 725G54_proj_address.Address_ID ASC";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
```

Edit 2:
I have tried switching to using count() instead of empty() and it found the variable as populated even when it shouldnt.

Comment: You will have to read the row, and if it does not exist then insert the input data into the table.

Comment: you will have to fetch the data and compare. How else are you going to compare?

Comment: @user1 I meant wether there was some way inside sql to do it or if i would have to fetch it to php and do it.

Comment: well, you could write a stored proc and send the data as a parameter to the proc and make proc return true or false based on whether the data exists or not

Comment: @user1 Would that allow me to find out what row it exists on? I need that to connect some tables.

Comment: yes, stored proc itself is a query thats stored in the database, only its faster and safer from hacks. you can do most of the things inside a proc as you can do when you pull it to php.

Comment: Looking at the update to your question, I'd do two things: first, change the initial `INSERT INTO 725G54_proj_address` to a `REPLACE INTO` so that you can be certain of having exactly one row for a given address; second, instead of `'$address'` in the `INSERT INTO 725G54_proj_LivesAt`, use the subquery `(SELECT id FROM 725G54_proj_address WHERE streetname=[...] AND streetnumber=[...])`. This way, you know you have exactly one autoincrement ID in _address for the address, and you don't have to query it out into your PHP code before the insert into _LivesAt.

Comment: Oh, and your code's vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should see to that before someone else does.

Comment: @AaronMiller I do some checks with PHP to see if Person B lives at same address as Person A,and if so i use the same Address_ID in the connecting table. I also do some protection aswell. This code was just the piece that does the insertion into the database.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are creating a many-to-one relationship (potentially) and should therefore be storing that data in a separate lookup table. What I suggest in that case is to first try to insert that row using an "INSERT IGNORE" statement 
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) and then use mysql_affected_rows() to see if it made a change. If it didn't then you know there's a duplicate row, which you can select, take the ID of, and then you're done.

As somebody mentioned in one of the comments above, you can make that into a stored process.

Comment: That seems rather backwards to me -- why is it better to use `INSERT IGNORE` and then follow with `SELECT` on failure, than to open with `SELECT` and decide whether to `INSERT` based on the result? Especially considering that `INSERT IGNORE`, like any `INSERT`, might fail for any number of reasons not related to the unique key constraint, it seems like doing it that way offers uncomfortably broad scope for subtle and hard-to-squash bugs, which the `SELECT`-then-`INSERT` method avoids.

Comment: I guess I was using the logic that you could potentially (and in most cases) avoid doing two queries. Not that a single select is a big deal. You're probably right there, as I'm certainly no guru of any sort when it comes to SQL... but this technique has worked in the past for me.

Comment: In our applications we use the stored procedure to do something like `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *) INSERT INTO` I guess it still technically is a second call, but as far as the code is concerned, it's just one. Or you could wrap it in a try..catch and if there's an error then it already exists...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've created proper keys on your table (i.e., a unique key across (name, streetname, streetnumber), or something similar), then MySQL [`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), or possibly [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html), might be useful here. The former will convert your `INSERT` statement into an `UPDATE` if the key to be inserted already exists in the table, and the latter will act as regular `INSERT` unless the key already exists, in which case it will first `DELETE` the existing row before `INSERT`ing the new data.

Of course, it's not exactly an onerous burden simply to `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n_existing FROM table WHERE...`, and then inspect `n_existing` in the result set to see whether a row already exists with the same key you're preparing to `INSERT`, and there is an argument to be made from the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) that it would be better to `SELECT` before `INSERT`ing than to use abstruse SQL statements which may not have been encountered before by anyone else who's going to be maintaining your code. Still, the option exists, should you prefer it.